# Wordpress strange 404 / Page Loads

Tags: wordpress, performance, woocommerce, http-status-code-404, wpml

I have a multilingual website running wordpress + woocommerce (with the latest versions) on www.gy-spot.com. The site loads pretty fine but once we select a particular product the page loads only after 15~20secs.

Doing a little research on firefox i get a loadind time on a GET procedure that returns a 404 but even though the page loads only after that amount of time (15~20sec).

I've done everything, from optimizing images to disabling every plugin, disabling heartbeat api, or even a theme change. Everything stays the same.

I've started a NewRelic account that shows a "most time consuming" on pages the refered /404 GET issue (44.1%).

The site is hosted on a VPS with 8GB RAM with 1GB dedicated only to this site.

Does anybody know what could cause this strange behaviour?
Thanks